# proportion of factors and dummies

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply, tidyr, data-manipulation

I have a data set full of factors and dummies, I want to see the proportion of each value after `dplyr::group_by(cyl)`

```
 mtcars; rownames(mtcars) <- NULL
    df <- mtcars[,c(2,8,9)]
    head(df)
     cyl vs am
    1   6  0  1
    2   6  0  1
    3   4  1  1
    4   6  1  0
    5   8  0  0
    6   6  1  0
```

Expected answer
I have in `cyl` 6 6 6 6 for `vs` column two of them is 1 two of them 0

```
   1    0
6 50% 50%
4 100% 0%
8 0%   100%
```

same as this for column `am` too

Comment: Can you clarify what your desired output `a` should look like with your example? Currently it looks like a list of your five factors, and for each factor has the proportions for each level.

Comment: hello, I added it. like prob.table(table())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a first crack:

```
(df 
    %>% pivot_longer(-cyl)       ## spread out variables (vs, am)
    %>% group_by(cyl,name)   
    %>% mutate(n=n())            ## obs per cyl/var combo
    %>% group_by(cyl,name,value) 
    %>% summarise(prop=n()/n)    ## proportion of 0/1 per cyl/var  
    %>% unique()                 ## not sure why I need this?
    %>% pivot_wider(id_cols=c(cyl,name),names_from=value,values_from=prop)
)
```

Results:

```
   cyl name     `0`    `1`
  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     4 am    0.273   0.727
2     4 vs    0.0909  0.909
3     6 am    0.571   0.429
...
```

Comment: one issue is that I think it will produce NAs when there are zero of a particular outcome; there are a lot Qs on StackOverflow (I think) that will explain how to deal with this, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60523702/keeping-zero-count-with-group-by-in-r