# set the name order in pivot_wider()

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr, data-manipulation

I am trying to do the same thing as below, except naming order changes. Got the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64783023/proportion-of-factors-and-dummies/64789012?noredirect=1#comment114556907_64789012)

```
  mtcars; rownames(mtcars) <- NULL
    df <- mtcars[,c(2,8,9)]
    head(df)
    (df 
      %>% pivot_longer(-cyl)       ## spread out variables (vs, am)
      %>% group_by(cyl,name)   
      %>% dplyr::mutate(n=n())            ## obs per cyl/var combo
      %>% group_by(cyl,name,value) 
      %>% dplyr::summarise(prop=n()/n)    ## proportion of 0/1 per cyl/var  
      %>% unique()                 ## not sure why I need this?
      %>% pivot_wider(id_cols=c(cyl,name),names_from=value,values_from=prop)
    )
```

Expected answer

```
 cyl name     `0`    `1`

 4   vs    0.0909  0.909
 4   am    0.273   0.727
 6   vs    0.429   0.571
 6   am    0.571   0.429
 8   vs    1        NA 
 8   am    0.857   0.143
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution involves adding three lines below your code.

Basically, you modify your variable `name` to be a factor with values coming in the order specified in `levels` so that it is internally coded as 1, 2, ...
Then you group by `cyl` and sort according to `name`

```
(df 
  %>% pivot_longer(-cyl)       ## spread out variables (vs, am)
  %>% group_by(cyl,name)   
  %>% dplyr::mutate(n=n())            ## obs per cyl/var combo
  %>% group_by(cyl,name,value) 
  %>% dplyr::summarise(prop=n()/n)    ## proportion of 0/1 per cyl/var  
  %>% unique() ## not sure why I need this?
  %>% pivot_wider(id_cols=c(cyl,name),names_from=value,values_from=prop)
  %>% mutate(name = factor(name, levels = c("vs", "am")))
  %>% group_by(cyl)
  %>% arrange(name, .by_group = TRUE)
)

# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   cyl [3]
    cyl name     `0`    `1`
  <dbl> <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     4 vs    0.0909  0.909
2     4 am    0.273   0.727
3     6 vs    0.429   0.571
4     6 am    0.571   0.429
5     8 vs    1      NA    
6     8 am    0.857   0.143
```

Answer (score 1):

Different take:

```
df %>% pivot_longer(!cyl) %>% group_by(cyl, name, value) %>% mutate(cnt = n()) %>% 
ungroup() %>% group_by(cyl, name) %>% mutate(prop = cnt/n()) %>% distinct() %>% 
pivot_wider(id_cols = c(cyl, name), names_from = value, values_from = prop) %>% 
arrange(cyl, desc(name))
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   cyl, name [6]
    cyl name     `0`    `1`
  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     4 vs    0.0909  0.909
2     4 am    0.273   0.727
3     6 vs    0.429   0.571
4     6 am    0.571   0.429
5     8 vs    1      NA    
6     8 am    0.857   0.143
>
```